# Why is listings not coloring the comments properly in the middle of the bash script?

Tags: listings, comments, bash

I have created a minimal example to illustrate the behavior. I have a `bash` code using `sed`. I want to use multiple substitutions using `sed`, placing each in a different line, so that I may add a comment to each o them. Unfortunately `listings` is experiencing some problem, it is not recognizing the comments and therefore it is not coloring them properly.

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{listings}
\author{authorname}
\begin{document}
\begin{lstlisting}[language=bash,commentstyle=\color{gray},showstringspaces=false]
cat a  # comment 1
sed "
  s/[^[:alnum:]'-]/ /g # comment 2
  s/\(.*\)/\L\1/ # comment 3
  s/\s\+/\n/g # comment 4
  " \
< text.txt
\end{lstlisting}
\end{document}
```

The output is displayed in the picture bellow:

[image]

How should one fix it in order to get proper comment coloring?

Comment: The comments in the `sed` command are not colored because there are inside a string, i.e., inside a pair of `"` characters. Most syntax highlighters in text editors or other highlighting packages (such as `minted`) also do not color these comments.

Comment: I thought on splitting the ```sed``` commands in file of its own (there would be no pair of ```"``` characters defining a string)... but even though, the comments do not get colored... and there is no language definition for ```sed```...  but using ```awk``` instead of ```bash``` managed to do the coloring I intended.